Замена модели игрока на geckolib
я делаю мод на версии майнкрафт 1.20.1 фабрик с использованием гекколиб но мне не удаётся заменить модель игрока
для начала есть 3 рендера , LivingEntity ,AbstractClientPlayerEntity и Entity
я не понимаю какой использовать для замены модели , я пробовал использовать AbstractClientPlayerEntity , но по итогу игра вылетала при переходе от третьего лица с ошибкой что не удаётся заменить полностью рендер (не только модели игрока но и вообще полностью всего)
через LivingEntity тоже не получается , он просто не получает данные в mixin хоть и рендер подключается и все регистрации рабоют, занимаюсь этим уже 4-й день , потратил на это около 20-ти часов
если ктонибудь знает подскажите пожалуйста какие нибудь методы или через что вообще можно это сделать , может быть используется mixin не PlayerEntityRenderer.class
у меня получалось присоединять стандартную модель сделаную в коде и заменять на неё игрока но не гекко
